Quadratic equations defining a smooth hyperplane section of the 10-dimensional spinor variety.
Let $X\subset \mathbb P^{14}$ be a smooth hyperplane section of the $10$-dimensional spinor variety $S^{10}\subset \mathbb P^{15}$. Is it possible to describe $X$ as a scheme-theoretic intersection of less than $9$ quadrics of $\mathbb P^{14}$?

No, less than 9 quadrics is not enough. This follows from Proposition 4.1 in [Kuznetsov, A. G. On linear sections of the spinor tenfold. I. Izv. Math. 82 (2018), no. 4, 694--751] which proves that the map
$$
\mathbb{P}^{15} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^9
$$
given by quadrics through $S$ is surjective onto a quadric $Q \subset \mathbb{P}^9$. Indeed, if we take less than 9 hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^9$, they will have a non-trivial intersection with $Q$, and the preimage of this intersection in $\mathbb{P}^{15}$ will be an extra component of the intersection of the corresponding quadrics.

Thank you very much for your answer. By your argument, we see that the 10-dimensional Spinor variety is not scheme-theoretically defined by less than 9  quadrics. Then the answer to my question follows from this and the surjectivity of $H^0(I_{X/\mathbb P^{15}}(2))\to H^0(I_{X\cap H/H}(2))$, where $H\subset \mathbb P^{15}$ is a hyperplane.
